# When we should NOT use neither [weak self] nor [unowned self]?

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

I've read several discussion on StackOverflow about when we should use `[weak self]` **or** `[unowned self]` in closures.

However, are there any cases when we don't have to use **neither** of them since Swift doesn't show any error or warning when we're just explicitly using `self` inside a closure.

For example, should we use `weak` or `unowned` here?

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.view.alpha = 0.0
}
```

Comment: In any of the cases that are **not** mentioned in the answers for when to **use them**?

Comment: Also have a look at the [Strong Reference Cycles for Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID56) part of the Swift programming language guide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [weak self] or [unowned self] if your closure can cause a Strong Reference Cycle.

This can occur if you **assign** the closure to a property of **self** and you refer to **self** or a property of **self** **inside** the closure itself. Closures are reference types, hence essentially the same rules apply to strong references as if you used normal classes.

As for your example, there is no need for `[weak self]` or `[unowned self]`, since you don't assign the closure to a variable inside the class to which `self` refers to, so there won't be a strong reference cycle.

For more information, check out the [Strong Reference Cycles for Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) part of the Swift programming language guide. Here is an example from the mentioned link of when a strong reference cycle can be caused by closures:

```
class HTMLElement {

    let name: String
    let text: String?

    lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
        if let text = self.text {
            return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
        } else {
            return "<\(self.name) />"
        }
    }

    init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }

}
```

Without `[unowned self]` in the closure of `asHTML`, a strong reference cycle will be caused by the closure assigned to `asHTML`. Changing the implementation of `asHTML` to the following solves this issue:

```
lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
    [unowned self] in
    if let text = self.text {
        return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
    } else {
        return "<\(self.name) />"
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, but what's the difference between these 2 implementations of asHTML var?

Comment: Accidentally left out the `[unowned self]` from the correct implementation, fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat opinion based, so I'll give my opinion :)

I generally base it on synchronicity. If a closure is Async, the calling instance may no longer exist when the closer is called and therefore `[weak self]` should be used. If a closure is synchronous, it's unnecessary and capturing a strong reference is fine.

This *could* be expanded to also include closures where you can reasonably expect your instance to remain valid when it's called (e.g. your View animation case), however be aware this makes an assumption that the closure and your usage of it will remain unchanged, so it could theoretically break at some point in the future. This less safe and makes future maintenance more difficult/dangerous.

In the case of an established and predictable API like UIView.animate, I personally tend to use strong self for the sake of brevity, but that's an evaluation you'll need to do yourself and it depends on the usage.

Also as noted in the comments, this is true of function-closures. Assigning a closure to another variable's property has a different set of issues.

As an aside, I have adopted the approach of weak-reference closures simply calling another method in my Type, e.g.

```
thing.doSomethingWithAClosure() { [weak self]
    self?.doSomething()
}
```

It simplifies the logic while also enforcing more functional/modular code.